# Registering Class methods as hook callbacks

Tags: plugins, hooks, oop

I'm not sure if I have done this correctly.

As I understand it:

if I have a class foo and a static method bar I can register that as the callback by passing the array `array("foo","bar")` as the function name.

If I have an instance of a class in $foo and want to call the method bar I pass the array `array($foo,'bar')`.

If I need to register an action inside the class itself would it work with `array($this,'bar')`?

Comment: Wouldn’t a test be faster than asking the question? ;) Yes, you can do this.

Comment: A test can help, but sometimes you look for feedback as well. I think it's okay to actually ask the question, and there is this rule, questioning the OPs motivation ... :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> If I need to register an action inside the class itself would it work with `array($this, 'bar')`?

Yes, it works. [`$this`<sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php) is referring to the concrete instance needed for the [callback](http://php.net/manual/en/language.pseudo-types.php#language.types.callback). That's exactly like the `$foo` example you give. It's just that `$this` is bit more special, but it represents basically the same and it works flawlessly with callbacks in PHP.

**Additional:**

> if I have a class foo and a static method bar I can register that as the callback by passing the array `array("foo","bar")` as the function name.

Yes you can do so, for the static function, you can write it as a string instead of the array as well: `foo::bar`, see [Callbacks <sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/manual/en/language.pseudo-types.php#language.types.callback). Might be handy.

Answer (score 2):

For static methods you can also do this:

```
['foo','bar']
```

when the following gives *Undefined class constant 'bar'*:

```
foo::bar
```

example - when specifying the $control_callback for `wp_add_dashboard_widget`